# How to fill multiple values returned from powershell script into HTML dropdownlist?

Tags: html, powershell, active-directory, html.dropdownlistfor

I am fetching the list of domains in the forest through my powershell script, I want to fill those values in dropdownlist. Based on the selected domain I want to load the AD groups in the other dropdownlist. I have the scripts ready but can't figure out the way to fill in the dropdownlists.

I am using System.Automation.Management library to a manage powershell scripts. Here's my function and the Script.

```
private string PowerShellExecutor(string script) {
    string outString = "";
    var shell = PowerShell.Create();
    shell.Commands.AddScript(script);
    var results = shell.Invoke();
    if (results.Count>0)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var psObj in results)
        {
            builder.Append(psObj.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");

        }
        outString = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
    }
    return outString;
}

<div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlDirectory", new SelectList(PowerShellExecutor(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Shell\\Get\\ADDomain.ps1")), "Select Domain", new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

My Script has this code : Get-ADForest | Select -ExpandProperty Domains
Which returns list of domains.

The dropdown needs to fill in the values:
Domain1
Domain2
..

Comment: is this supposed to me MVC?

Comment: You probably need to split the results of the AD query on line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Updated Function That is Working:

```
public List<SelectListItem> PowerShellExecutorLst(string scriptPath)
    {
        string outString = "";
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
        shell.Commands.AddCommand(scriptPath);
        var results = shell.Invoke();
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var psObj in results)
            {
                builder.Append(psObj.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");

            }
            outString = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
        }
        List<string> result = outString.Split(new char[] { '\n' }).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> listItems = result.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text=s }).ToList();
        shell.Dispose();
        return listItems;
    }
```